# Function gets() doesn't stop to take input

Tags: c, string, visual-studio, gets, puts

I'm trying to take an input into 2 strings using the `gets()` function (and I must use this function only)

but when I run the program the console just continues into the second `gets()` without even stopping to get the first input.

When I debug I don't see any input being inserted into the string `cityName`, its just passing over it.

I know also, that there is an issue with the buffer when handling strings, is there a way to "clean" the buffer using the `puts()` and `gets()` functions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
void main() {
    int z;
    char cityName[50];
    char Coordinates[50]; 
    scanf("%d", &z);
    printf("Please enter city name:\n");
    gets(cityName);
    printf("Please enter city coordinates\n");
    gets(Coordinates);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the call to `scanf("%d", &z);`, when you input an integer, and press ENTER, the number is consumed by `scanf`, but the new line is still in the buffer, causing the next `gets()` to get only that new line.

The solution, first, get rid of `gets()`, I don't know why it's the only function that you must use, it may cause buffer overflow thus dangerous, use `fgets()` to replace it. Second, use something to consume the new line, you have more than one options. For example, use one extra call to `fgets()`.

Also, use `int main(void)`, it's undefined behavior to use declare `void main()`.

Comment: Ive seen many issues about the dangers in gets() the things is, that its not my call at all..i must use it and only it.

Comment: @user3921 Well, tell whoever made the decision that you must use `gets()` the danger of it. Furthermore, it's already removed from the C standard library in the newest standard(C11).

Comment: I think I managed to handle it, I uses a while loop and uses getchar until I reached /n after every input..seems to be working. I know that its stupid to use gets and puts but those are my instructions and I don't want to fail class because of this kind of stuff. thanks

Comment: @user3921: Tell your instructor that he should get the clue and actually *warn* people not to use `gets()`, instead of forcing them into it.